# The Output error for different instances

Tags: c++, parsing

I am solving the math expressions through predefined grammer rules. Here is the program. It works for all the inputs, when i enter in the console window () and then one step back and try to insert an expression like (2+3). I am getting ')' not found error. If i type '(' followed by expression then ')', The results are ok. Can anyone please tell me how this error is coming. Here is the error code

> (2); this ths the expression i typed..
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: ) IS EXPECTED

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Token { // Defining the Token class
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
    Token (char ch){ // Constructor 1
        kind = ch;
        value = 0;
    }
    Token (char ch, double val){// Constructor 2
        kind = ch;
        value = val;
    }
};
Token get_token (); // declaration of get_token function
double expression (); // declaration of expression function
double term (); // declaration of term function
double primary (); // declaration of primary function


int main (){
    cout << "> ";
    double t = expression ();
    cout << " = " << t ;
    return 0;
}

double expression (){ // expression function definition

    double left = term(); // term can be an expression ist rule in expression
    //cout << "The left value in expression is " << left;
    Token t = get_token();
    while (t.kind != ';' && t.kind != ')') { // expression can be terminated by either ';' or ')'(sub expression)
        switch (t.kind){
                case '+':
                    left += term();// expression + term rule no 2
                    t = get_token();
                    break;
                case '-':
                    left -= term(); // expression - term rule no 3
                    t = get_token();
                    break;
                default:;
        }
    }
   if (t.kind == ')')
       cin.putback (t.kind);
   return left;
}

double term (){ // term function definition

    double left = primary(); // primary can be a term, first rule of term
    Token t = get_token();
    while (t.kind != ';' && t.kind != '+' && t.kind != '-' && t.kind != ')'){
        switch (t.kind){
            case '*' :
                left *= primary();
                t = get_token();
                break;
            case '/' :{
                double d = primary();
                if (d == 0) error ("divide by zero");
                left /= d;
                t = get_token();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    if (t.kind == ';' || t.kind == '+' || t.kind == '-' || t.kind == ')')
        cin.putback(t.kind);
    return left;
}
double primary () {
    double d;
    Token t = get_token();
    //cout << "The token value is " << t.value << " token operator is" << t.kind;
    switch (t.kind){
        case '(' :{
            d = expression();
            t = get_token();
            if (t.kind != ')') error (") IS EXPECTED");
            break;
        }
        case '8' :
            d = t.value;
            break;
    }
    return d;
}


Token get_token (){
    char ch;
    //cout << "Enter the expression in get_token: ";
    cin >> ch;

    switch (ch){
        case '(':
        case ')':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return Token(ch);
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        {       // Any variable defined in switch should be in a block
            cin.putback(ch);
            double val;
            cin >> val;
            return Token('8',val);
            break;
        }
        default :;

    }
    return Token (';');
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you running this on? If you "back out", the program might actually be reading the "back out" as a backspace character (`'\x08'`) so that the actual input is something like `"(2+3_\x08)"`

Comment: Okay, your first problem is that you've got spaghetti code. Don't pepper cin throughout a bunch of different functions. It makes it very difficult to work out what the state of the input stream is at any given time. Use it once to get the entire input, then parse the input into a list of tokens, then organize those tokens into your expression. That way, instead of having to read over the entire program trying to guess where the bug is at, you'll be able to just look at the tokens coming out of your tokenize() function and see if they're correct.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings This is one of [Stroustrup's own example programs](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator08buggy.cpp). I won't comment on that, but let you come to your own conclusions ;-).

Comment: Yesomite. I am not using 'del' button, with arrow keys, moved to the desired location and replaced with new digit. It seems the way i am entering is not correct. I should probably use 'del' only. otherwise the results are not as expected..

Comment: It's still spaghetti code. Also, "Here's a program with 3 bugs in it! Guess where they are!" probably isn't a good template to start your program with.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings There's quite a few more bugs than three in that code. The most important one being: If you write code like this, stop writing code NOW ;-). But  that's my opinion.

Comment: I am a novice programmer...Yes it needs improvement..I assumed user enters expressions correctly.. i am not able to find out.. can you give some clue..if user enters the input correctly.it should work..

Comment: IMHO, your current problem is the way you *step back*. Normal console program correctly accept line editing. As already asked by dhke: what is your OS?